# Доверстать макет, подогрев мозгов

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

При растяжении левого блока по высоте, правый блок тоже должен растягиваться

При растяжении правого блока по высоте, левый блок тоже должен растягиваться (сейчас работает)

[Не доделанный пример](https://jsfiddle.net/Zoxon/rxyUH/)

[image]
<sub>(источник: [pixs.ru](http://i6.pixs.ru/storage/3/3/1/htmlpng_5113058_11357331.png))</sub>

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.page {
}
.header {
    height: 48px;
    background: green;
}
.main {
    background: gray;
}
.sidebar {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 230px;
    float: left;
}
.content-wrapper {
    margin-left: 230px;
    background: lightblue;
    padding: 50px 0;
}
.content {
    width: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: yellow;
}
.footer {
    height: 48px;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">header</div>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="content">content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">footer</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

немного переделал css, зато надежно http://jsfiddle.net/rxyUH/1/

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.page {
}
.header {
    height: 48px;
    background: green;
}
.main {
    background: gray;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.sidebar {
    width: 230px;
    display: table-cell;
}
.content-wrapper {
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: lightblue;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 50px 0;
}
.content {
    width: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: yellow;
}
.footer {
    height: 48px;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">header</div>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="content">content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">footer</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: ну да табличка надёжнее флоатов)